# Selenium web driver with Python -Windows Handles -list index out of range

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to navigate between pages in I.e USING PYTHON\Selenium\webdriver.
Code below
I'm getting "list index out of range" when I want the driver to work with new window opened in the browswer

Scenario
Open page , click on button , write something, click enter >> it direct you to new page which I want to work on..

Code:

```
# Selenium WebDriver
# The IE Webdriver located in the Automation LMS Solution
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import sys
from Environment import *

driver=webdriver.Ie() # use Internet explorer
driver.get("https://www.google.co.il/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2dGpVoj5AayI8Qf_yoigDg")
Windows_Before=driver.window_handles[0] # define the current window
TextFieldPress=driver.find_element_by_name("q") # Find element by name for instance
TextFieldPress.send_keys("O") # write from keyboard
TextFieldPress.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) # press on the keyboard etner\ctrl\alt etc
Windows_After=driver.window_handles[1]# this is define the window after the Enter press
driver.switch_to_window(Windows_After) # the driver set to the new window 
driver.close
```

Comment: Try waiting a while after the ENTER press before looking for the new window handle to be ready.

Comment: Hi,Sorry but it didn't help (add 5 sec delay between enter to switch

Answer (score 0):

I can search for a keyword and print the text of 1st search result successfully.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
import os
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from random import randint
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import MySQLdb
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import autoit

class SprintTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):       
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.get("https://www.google.co.il/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2dGpVoj5AayI8Qf_yoigDg")
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test_input(self):
        a = self.driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        a.send_keys('O')
        autoit.send("{ENTER}")
        a = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/h3/a')
        b=a.text
        print b

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

Comment: I didn't understand how it has something to do with my question

Comment: "Scenario Open page , click on button , write something, click enter >> it direct you to new page which I want to work on"........my code can successfully fetch data from the page you want to work ie search result page....is it not what you need?